# Remove Multiple Objects from the group of Array

Tags: javascript

I would like to splice the whole Object inside the array "Docs > Exam" which has "Pass":"NO"
i have tried this

```js
 var docs = [
               {"Id":1,"Name":"First","Exam":[{"Pass":"No"},{"Sub":"T1"}]},
               {"Id":2,"Name":"Second","Exam":[{"Pass":"Yes"},{"Sub":"T2"}]},
               {"Id":3,"Name":"Third","Exam":[{"Pass":"No"},{"Sub":"T3"}]}
               ];

for (var i = docs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     for (var j = docs[i].Exam.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
             if (docs[i].Exam[j].Pass == 'No') {
                 docs.splice(docs[i],1);
             }
        }
    }
    
console.log(docs);
```

I need only the docs with this object only

```
{"Id":2,"Name":"Second","Exam":[{"Pass":"Yes"},{"Sub":"T2"}
```

Comment: You're using `splice` slightly incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example):

```
docs = docs.filter(doc => doc.Exam.some(exam => exam.Pass === 'Yes'))
```

Comment: Uhm, replace `'Yes'` to `'No'`  (requirement: " _Exam which has "Pass":"NO"_ ")

Comment: but in his example of what he needs is the `'Yes'` one

Comment: @KarelG No. The question is to *remove* exams that are not passed, i.e. it should *keep* the ones that are passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const isExamPassed = exam => exam.Pass === 'Yes';

1. docs.filter(doc => isExamPassed(doc.Exam[0]));
2. docs.map(doc => doc.Exam[0])
       .filter(isExamPassed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.filter` API.

```js
var docs = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "First",
    "Exam": [{
      "Pass": "No"
    }, {
      "Sub": "T1"
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Second",
    "Exam": [{
      "Pass": "Yes"
    }, {
      "Sub": "T2"
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Third",
    "Exam": [{
      "Pass": "No"
    }, {
      "Sub": "T3"
    }]
  }
];

console.log("Before Filtering: ", docs.length);
docs = docs.filter(function(doc, index) {
  var bIsPass = true;
  for (var j = doc.Exam.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
    if (doc.Exam[j].Pass === "No") {
      bIsPass = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return bIsPass;
});

console.log("Before Filtering: ", docs.length);
console.log("Result :", docs);
```